# Page 37 of The Swift Programming Language: func works in code but not as method of a struct

Tags: swift, methods, struct

I'm trying an exercise from page 37 of the Swift Programming Language book from Apple Here's a    struct with two enums (from the Swift Programming reference):

```
 struct Card {
        var rank: Rank
        var suit: Suits

    func description() -> String {
        return "The \(rank.ofRank()) of \(suit.ofSuit())"
    }

    func createDeck() -> (Card[]){
        var deck = Card []()
        for rangeOfSuits in 1...4 {
            for rangeOfRanks in 1...13 {
                println("\(rangeOfRanks)")
                deck.append(Card(rank: Rank.fromRaw(rangeOfRanks)!, suit: Suits.fromRaw(rangeOfSuits)!))
            }
        }
        return (deck)
    }
}
```

That second method: createDeck() doesn't work. When used

```
 myDeck.createDeck()
```

gives compile error: "Card() does not have a member 'createDeck'"
However, remove it from the Struct and everything works fine:

```
func createDeck () -> (Card[]){
    var deck = Card []()
    for rangeOfSuits in 1...4 {
        for rangeOfRanks in 1...13 {
            deck.append(Card(rank: Rank.fromRaw(rangeOfRanks)!, suit: Suits.fromRaw(rangeOfSuits)!))
        }
    }
    return (deck)
}
    myDeck = createDeck()
    myDeck.count             //yields 52, as it should
    myDeck[51].description() //yields King of Clubs as it should.
```

My answer to the question is: on page 384 of the Swift Programming Language:

“Type Methods
Instance methods, as described above, are methods that are called on an instance of a particular type. You can also define methods that are called on the type itself. These kinds of methods are called type methods. **You indicate type methods** for classes by writing the keyword class before the method’s func keyword, and type methods **for structures and enumerations by writing the keyword static before the method’s func keyword.**”

I am not clear on **why** one has to do this, but the method works when I add "static" in front of it and fails when I don't.

Comment: on my side it works well with `struct`, like `let cards: Card = Card(rank: Rank.Ace, suit: Suit.Clubs); cards.createDeck()` runs like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

`myDeck.createDeck()` by itself makes no sense because you have no Card. A struct is like a class; to send an instance method to it, you need an instance. Instantiate first:

```
var myDeck = Card() // not really, though
myDeck.createDeck()
```

However, *that* code won't work either, because `()` is not a valid initializer for Card. So replace the first line by an actual initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the static keyword to make a struct func that does not need an instance to exist.

In your example:

```
struct Card {
// ... 
static func createDeck() -> (Card[]){
    var deck = Card []()
    for rangeOfSuits in 1...4 {
        for rangeOfRanks in 1...13 {
           println("\(rangeOfRanks)")
           deck.append(Card(rank: Rank.fromRaw(rangeOfRanks)!, suit: Suits.fromRaw(rangeOfSuits)!))
            }
        }
        return (deck)
    }
}
```

Now you may use:

```
var deck = Card.createDeck()
```